# Terminal loses focus on Mac OS X when calling java.awt.Color.*

Tags: java, macos, awt

I'm writing a command line program in java, and using java.awt.Color for utility purposes (there is no GUI involved). But when I reference java.awt.Color.RED (for instance) it causes the terminal to lose focus. This only happens on Mac, it works fine on Linux and Windows. I suspect that the static initializers are the problem, but I'm not really sure where to go from here, as this is not a problem that I can debug (since the problem isn't going to happen if the terminal doesn't have focus to begin with).

Here is a small code snippet that demonstrates the problem. (Build the jar, then run it from the terminal.)

```java
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Note that we have focus right now. Calling System.out.println(Color.RED) in 5 seconds.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(java.awt.Color.RED);
        System.out.println("Note now that focus has been lost.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Ending program.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at your Dock, you'll that your app will spawn a Java icon, which now has the focus. And I guess you're right, that this has something to do with calling the `Color` constructor and initialising basic gui stuff.

Comment: Right, so, I guess the question is, how do I prevent that from happening, or, alternatively, how do I get the terminal to regain focus.

Comment: Well, then you like to work with the terminal, then you shouldn't need to call AWT/Swing-Stuff, since it won't be displayed anyway. So consider writing your own basic `Color` class which does exactly what you need and nothing else (like loading gui libraries).

Comment: In this case, that's an option, because it's my own code, but I wonder what the solution would be if this were 3rd party code.